# jQuery select every 3,4,5,6,7 and addClass - But repeat it

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress blog that is shows 20 posts.

I want to add a class to every (2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20)

So I do NOT want to add the class to the ( 1,2 and 10,11 )

I tried css with selectors nth-child(3n+1)... this was not the solution.

```
$('.article-box:nth-child(1n+3)').addClass('small-river');
```

I also tried .slice(2,3,4,5,6,7,8) etc... but I couldn't get this to repeat.

```
$('.article-box').slice(3,4,5).addClass('small-river');
```

Comment: add a counter variable in the while loop and when it reaches these numbers it can then if it reaches these numbers then you have the functionality happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add indexes you wants to skip to the following array. Plz note that i've used `0` based indexing.

```js
 var skipIndex = [1, 2, 10, 11];

$('.article-box').each(function(index) {
  
  if(skipIndex.indexOf(index) == -1) {
    $(this).addClass('small-river');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.small-river {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
    <div class="article-box">Lorem ipsum</div>
```